# how to create dynamically nav bar and when i click nav bar it will create listview in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to creating a nav bar dynamically and create a listview when i click the first tab in nav bar. it will created fine. but when click second tab ,the first tab content not hiding automatically it shows each tab same....how to hide it automatically?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,     maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h1>Call List</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
        </div>   
    </div>
<script>
 $(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){    
    $('[data-role="header"]').append('<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li id="pageone"><a>Page One</a></li><li id="pagetwo"><a>Page Two</a></li><li id="pagethree"><a>Page three</a></li><li id="pagefour"><a>Page four</a></li></ul></div>');
    $('[data-role="navbar"]').navbar();
    $('#pageone').click(function(){
     $('[data-role="content"]').html('<ul id="List" data-role="listview"></ul>');
        $('#List').html('<li><a>Item1</a></li>');
        $('#List').listview();
        $("#list").listview("refresh");             
  });
  $('#pagetwo').click(function(){
     $('[data-role="content"]').html('<ul id="List1" data-role="listview"></ul>');
        $('#List1').html('<li><a>Item2</a></li>');
        $('#List1').listview();
        $("#list1").listview("refresh");            
  });
  $('#pagethree').click(function(){
     $('[data-role="content"]').html('<ul id="List2" data-role="listview"></ul>');
        $('#List2').html('<li><a>Item3</a></li>');
        $('#List2').listview();
        $("#list2").listview("refresh");            
  });
  /* $('#pagefour').click(function(){
     $('[data-role="content"]').html('<ul id="List3" data-role="listview"></ul>');
        $('#List3').html('<li><a>Item4</a></li>');
        $('#List3').listview();
        $("#list3").listview("refresh");            
  });*/
});
</script>   
</body>
```

Comment: how add a code here? am new one to this blog?

Comment: Click edit you can copy past your code but ensure to use { } (the logo on the editor)

Comment: Don't understand.Explain more what you want?

Comment: i have created 4 tabs for navigation..i didn't enter the code for fourth tab.if i click foruth tab simply means it will be show empty space.but in my code it will show what i clicked last tab in that content showing the same in fourth tab also how to hide it??can u understand?

Comment: @KalaiPrakash Yes understood.You want to display blank in fourth tab?

Comment: ya...correct @homen

Comment: @KalaiPrakash check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add these lines with your `javaScript` code:

```
   $('#pagefour').click(function(){
    $('[data-role="content"]').empty();
  });
```

Comment: if i add some content in fourth means whatwill haopen into this code if am using?

Comment: if you add something it will work.But add your code after `$('[data-role="content"]').empty();` line.

Comment: If you don't know how to accept you can check here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow